# Oh_My_ZSH! error on Mac: ".oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:66: command not found: rm"

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

out of the blue `oh_my_zsh` throws this when starting the terminal on "my" mac

```sh
/User/<...>/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:66: command not found: rm
compdump:136: command not found: mv
detect-clipboard:33: command not found: uname
/Users/<...>/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh:235: command not found: awk
/usr/local/Cellar/powerlevel9k/0.6.7/functions/utilities.zsh:82: command not found: uname
prompt_context:13: command not found: whoami
prompt_background_jobs:1: command not found: wc
prompt_background_jobs:2: command not found: awk
```

breaking completely my `.zshrc`
example (I assure you flutter is there)

```sh
which flutter                              ✔  2332  10:09:21
flutter not found
prompt_context:13: command not found: whoami
prompt_background_jobs:1: command not found: wc
prompt_background_jobs:2: command not found: awk
```

I cannot access my `.zshrc` through terminal

```
 ~  nano ~/.zshrc                                         ✔  2333  12:57:43
zsh: command not found: nano
prompt_context:13: command not found: whoami
prompt_background_jobs:1: command not found: wc
prompt_background_jobs:2: command not found: awk
 ~  sudo nano ~/.zshrc                                127 ↵  2334  12:58:30
zsh: command not found: sudo
prompt_context:13: command not found: whoami
prompt_background_jobs:1: command not found: wc
prompt_background_jobs:2: command not found: awk
```

also `Finder => Press Cmd + Shift + .` doesn't seem to work,
any other way I can access it?
or any suggestion about how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Aside from the fact, that obviously your PATH is messed up (or empty), why did you tag this question with _bash_, since there is nothing related to bash in your question. Just check your startup files (.zprofile, .zshrc etc.) at which point PATH gets destroyed.

Comment: @user1934428 I've updated the question, any idea how to check my .zshrc w/o terminal?

Comment: Your terminal is fine; you can use the full path to your editor: `/usr/bin/nano ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: @FrancescoIapicca : Just use any pager (`less`, `more`, `pg`) or editor. Also, since it is PATH-related, check **all** the zsh startup files relevant for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @user1934428 and @chepner

I solved as follow

in a text editor:

open file: `cmd + o`

go to folder: `cmd + shift + g`

type: `~/`

see hidden files: `cmd + shift + .`

select: `.zshrc`

fix the mess

Comment: 1. The first step is just to open your editor, Vscode, or other.
2. Mechanically follow the steps listed by @Francesco to the letter.
It worked well for me.